# Avoid hardcoding of variables for Compile by using a list

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I want to automatically `Compile` an expression in between a routine of certain analytical manipulations. The number of arguments for the function may change for every run, so I would like to avoid hardcoding the arguments into my call of `Compile`. Consider this MWE:

```
vars = {x, y};
expr = Sin[x + y];
fun1 = With[{e = expr}, Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, e]];
```

The disadvantage here is that I need to provide `{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}` as variables explicitly. I would rather like to be able to do something like

```
fun2 = With[{e = expr, v = Transpose[{vars, ConstantArray[_Real, Length@vars]}]},
            Compile[v, e]]
```

where knowing `vars` in advance allows me to avoid manually computing `v`, print it and then copy-paste into `Compile`. All variants of `fun2` I could come up with boil down to the issue that `Compile` only recognizes a single variable as input. Is there any way to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished through `Hold[]` trickery:

```
vars = {x, y}; expr = Sin[x + y];

fun1 = Hold[Compile][Transpose[PadRight[{vars}, {2, Automatic}, {_Real}]],
                     expr] // ReleaseHold;
```

An alternative is to start with a `Hold[]` expression, inject any needed changes with `With[]`, and then use `Apply[]`:

```
fun1 = With[{vlist = Transpose[PadRight[{vars}, {2, Automatic}, {_Real}]]},
            Compile @@ Hold[vlist, expr]];
```

Test:

```
fun1[π/6, π/3]
   1.
```

Comment: better perhaps to start with a `HoldComplete` than a `List`

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it works with `Hold[]` or `HoldComplete[]` for the second version, because the part that assembles the sequence of arguments won't fire inside a `Hold[]`, unless you `MapAt[]` an `Evaluate[]`.

Comment: I meant something like `With[{vars=varList}, Compile@@Hold[vars, expr]]`. Allows you to keep `expr` held.

Comment: Yes, injection should work; I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot. I clearly need to get used to `Hold` a lot more. Nice and compact solution. Side question: Is there a specific reason why you are using the `PadRight` based way to generate the list of variables instead of my way? Is it just personal taste or is there more behind it?

Comment: @Lukas, I use `PadRight[]` in case `vars` has a lot of variables in it, and I don't want to bother counting. Your method with `ConstantArray[]` is fine and equivalent.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Often I do things like this with `Replace` as a destructuring function. Here's a super convoluted example that uses `Replace`, `Hold,` and `Thread` to define a `Compile` spec that holds all its arguments and auto-detects its variables (also not gonna lie it was kinda fun to write):

```
Options[compileWithVars] =
  Join[
   {
    "TypeMap" -> Automatic
    },
   Options[Compile]
   ];
compileWithVars[
  varList : {__Symbol} | Automatic : Automatic, 
  expr_, 
  ops___?OptionQ
  ] :=
 With[
  {
   varsHeld =
    Replace[Hold[varList], 
     {
      Hold[Automatic] :>
       DeleteDuplicates@
        Cases[Hold[expr], 
         s_Symbol?(Function[Null, Context[#] == $Context, 
             HoldFirst]) :> Hold[s],
         Infinity
         ],
      l_List :> Thread[l]
      }
     ],
   tm =
    Replace[
     Lookup[Flatten@{ops}, "TypeMap", Automatic ],
     Automatic :> {_ -> {_Real}}
     ]
   },
  Replace[
   Thread[
    Map[Replace[Join[#, Hold @@ (# /. tm)], Hold[l__] :> Hold[{l}]] &,
      varsHeld ], Hold],
   {
    Hold[vl : {__List}] :>
     Apply[
      Compile,
      HoldComplete[
       vl,
       expr,
       Evaluate@FilterRules[
         Flatten@{ops},
         Options[Compile]
         ]
       ]
      ],
    sheesh_ :>
     Failure["BadVarList",
      <|

       "MessageTemplate" :> "Var spec `` is invalid (originally ``)",
       "MessageParameters" :> {sheesh, 
         HoldForm @@ Thread[varsHeld, Hold]}
       |>
      ]
    }
   ]
  ]
```

Then we do it like so:

```
compileWithVars[Sin[x + y]]
```

[image: blah]

Or we can tell it that we expect `x` to be a `{_Integer, 1}` and everything else to default to `{_Real, 2}`:

```
compileWithVars[z*Cos[θ]*Sin[x + y], 
 "TypeMap" -> {Hold[x] -> {_Integer, 1}, _ -> {_Real, 2}}]
```

[image: blib]

Comment: Might be a useful addition: ``Reduce`FreeVariables[]`` will allow you to extract the variables from an arbitrary expression.

Comment: @J.M. Ooh very useful. Can it extract them in a held manner?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, sorry.

Comment: @b3m2a1 This is great! Clearly very useful for many applications. Good to hear that you actually enjoyed preparing an answer to my question ;)

Comment: @J.M. seems it doesn't dig into things wrapped in `Hold` which is too bad. I'd prefer if it did but just returned that variables in held form.

Comment: @b3m2a1 is it also possible to inject Compile options to it ? like Parallelization or make the compiled function listable ?

Comment: @user49047 yeah just pass them as options

Comment: @b3m2a1 changing  Options[Compile] with {RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True} did not do it for me !!! any idea ?

Comment: @user49047 did you do ``compileWithVars[expr, {"RuntimeAttributes" -> {Listable},  "Parallelization" -> True}]``? That seems to work for me.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks found my mistake